# How can i put radiobutton in listview

Tags: android, eclipse

How am i going to do this,i want to display 1 radio button and 1 checkbox in

listview,can you help me please on this what should i do i am still beginner on this
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't, or at least you shouldn't. Don't place focusable widgets within a ListView. Research the `Checkable` interface, it may support what you want to do.

Comment: refer this previous post it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562353/code-to-add-both-checkbox-and-radiobutton-in-same-listview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want listView with RadioButton and CheckBox, you can implement this using TableLayout, TableRow, and ScrollPane. But still if you want to do it, then use BaseAdapter.

I think you need to implement a custom Adapter (ie extend to BaseAdapter class) BaseAdapter class is an abstart class, which already implements the ListAdapter, SpinnerAdapter, and Adapter Interface, and has the basic grounds from building up the Custom Adapter..

Comment: can you please see the link that Aerrow posted,that's what i mean.is that listview?

Comment: My purpose is i want to practice coding in android and getting familiar with it.

Comment: I have struggled a lot with custom adapter and the listview, i referred the head first series for android, but the code in it didnt worked, it was later through trial and error, i got my funda right.. Frankly speaking android is not fully abt coding but how to do the things right, if you have a decent knowledge and experience coding in java, you can quickly get a good grip over android... best of luck for your quest in android world

Comment: what is abt coding? and head first series for android?